# Inconsistent upload/PUT access to Amazon AWS S3 with custom permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, zencoder, amazon-policy

I have an application that uploads videos to an S3 bucket, and then creates a custom policy to allow another user (for the Zencoder service) to grab the files, and upload the transcoded files back into the bucket.

Below is the current custom policy I give to the user during transcoding. Basically I give full read permission to the entire bucket, but I only allow the user to PUT files into a specific nested folder.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUserToListContentsOfBucket",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUserToListContentsOfBucketFolders",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUserS3ActionsOfSpecificFolder",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET/some/nested/folder/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This works for the most part, but in the ~1,000 files transferred over by Zencoder, there's usually one or two that fail with a `403 Forbidden` error. I'm not sure why, since files were correctly transferred both before and after the error.

Is there any reason Amazon AWS S3 / IAM would send a `403 Access Denied` when such a permission is provided?

Comment: By fails means they fail to load or you get that error message while uploading the files?

Comment: So the order is: (1) I upload the video file to S3, (2) I tell Zencoder to transcode the video file, (3) Zencoder grabs the original video file, (4) Zencoder uploads some files to S3, (5) Zencoder fails to upload a file with the `403 Access Denied` message, (6) Zencoder is successful at uploading other files after the failure in #5.

Comment: What is the format of the video file that fails? is it same format or random format that fails.

Comment: I'm always using the same format, `mp4`. Sometimes it fails, sometimes it succeeds. I'm transcoding videos into "mp4", "hls", and "dash". It typically seems to be "hls" or "dash" files that fail to be transferred to S3.

Comment: Can the failed file be subsequently uploaded?

Comment: I believe so. If I run through the same process again with the same video, it will sometimes succeed, and sometimes fail - so I don't believe it is specific to the file that is trying to be uploaded.

Comment: Is "careem" a user on your database?

Comment: I don't know if I understand. Are you talking an IAM user? If so, no, "careem" is not a user. Is that a typical user to have?